# Fail with error 'ERC20: insufficient allowance'

Tags: solidity, erc-20

Getting ERC20: insufficient allowance even I'm calling **approve** function before calling **transferFrom** function in **getRewards** function, don't know what I'm missing in it.

Cafe Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

// Uncomment this line to use console.log
// import "hardhat/console.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/IERC20.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract Cafe is Ownable {
    address public cafeToken;

    function setCafeToken(address _cafeToken) public onlyOwner {
        cafeToken = _cafeToken;
    }

    //send token to other receipent
    function sendToken(
        address _receiverAddress,
        uint _tokenAmount
    ) public onlyOwner {
        require(_tokenAmount > 0, "token should be more than 0");

        IERC20(cafeToken).transfer(_receiverAddress, _tokenAmount);
    }

    function getRewards() public {
        require(
            IERC20(cafeToken).balanceOf(msg.sender) >= 10000000000000000000,
            "you should have more then 10 tokens..."
        );
        IERC20(cafeToken).approve(msg.sender, 10000000000000000000);
        IERC20(cafeToken).transferFrom(
            msg.sender,
            address(this),
            10000000000000000000
        );
    }   
}
```

Cafe Token Contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract CAFToken is ERC20 {
    constructor(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        address cafeAddress
    ) ERC20("Cafe", "CAF") {
        _mint(cafeAddress, initialSupply); // mint intial supply to cafe contract
    }
}
```

first I'm deploying **Cafe** Contract and then **cafeToken** contract with deployed address of **cafe** contract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `approve()` call inside the `getRewards()` function approves 10000000000000000000 tokens from `Cafe` (*owner*) to be spendable by `msg.sender` (*spender*).

However, you actually want that the `msg.sender` approves the number of tokens to be spent by the `Cafe` contract, i.e. the `msg.sender` is the owner of tokens and the `Cafe` contract the spender.

This is only possible (leaving permit functionality out of scope) via the `msg.sender` making a transaction beforehand calling:

```
IERC20(cafeToken).approve(address(Cafe), 10000000000000000000)
```

Inside the `getRewards()` function, you could add a check ensuring the allowance for `Cafe` is sufficient, e.g. by using something like:

```
require(IERC20(cafeToken).allowance(msg.sender, address(this)) >= 10000000000000000000, "Insufficient allowance");
```

Note that in the `allowance()` call, `msg.sender` is the owner of the token, and `address(this)` is the spender.

Comment: Thank you @merkleplant, It's really very helpful to me an Issue has been fixed

Comment: happy to have helped! Could you then pls mark my comment as "answers the question"? This helps more folks to find this discussion :)

Comment: Yes, it fixed my issue but according to my research, we shouldn't call this approval and allowance function from backend (solidity), we should always call these from front end only.